# Why different results from "WHERE EXISTS()" and WHERE id IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get more results with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT table2.id FROM table2
        WHERE table1.id = table2.id
)
```

Than from this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE table1.id NOT IN (
        SELECT table2.id FROM table2
)
```

Why is this? I thought they were identical?
By the way, `table2` has some NULL values in the `id` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not identical.

When the subquery returns `NULL`, then the outer query returns *no results at all*.  The reason is that `NULL` *could* match any value -- it means "unknown value" not "missing value" semantically.  And an unknown value could match anything.  In actual fact, the condition returns `NULL` in this case, which is treated as `false`.

For this reason, I strongly, strongly recommend never using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  Use `NOT EXISTS`.

If you do, then you can do a `NULL` check:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id NOT IN (
        SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE table2.id IS NOT NULL
                       );
```

However, in my experience, you'll leave out the `NULL` check at some crucial time, and think that there are no non-matches when there are.